# Unable to run JUnit test in IntelliJ

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I wanted to start project using TDD. Created the test directory and later changed it to package that is integrated with src direcotry. In both cases I get the same error:

> Class not found: "tests.objectsTest"

I tried different techniques of importing JUnit jar and none solved problem. Also I tried to rename my test class but it gives no solutons whatsoever.

It seems that IntelliJ or JUnit changes name of the test class. Shouldn't it be `objectsTest.tests`?

I am using JUnit version 4.12 and latest IntelliJ EAP.

This is my project structure:

Project:

```
-.idea
-src
  -logic
  -objects
-tests
  -test
   -test.java
```

src and tests are directories marked as Source and Test. Every package except test is empty. On my other PC with IntelliJ Community Edition everything works fine but on EAP there is this bug. Unfortunatelly I have to use EAP.

**test.java code:**

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;

public class test {

    @Test
    public void canCreateInhabitant(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your test class complete with package informations.

Comment: Check your casing. The java filename must exactly (inlcuding casing) match the class name. This is sometimes a problem on windows because the filesystem is case insensititive but the compiler is not. Hint: class names usually start uppercase.

Comment: At first I thought that the uppercase might solve problem (shame that I forgot to do so in the first place...). Matching the class name doesn't work either.

Comment: Try to name your class `FooTest` or something else just to rule out problems related to your naming. Something in your project seems to be named `objectTest`. Maybe your run configuration tries to use a missing class?

Comment: Before writing last comment I renamed the test class to ObjectTests, so naming is not the case. There is nothing named objectTest. I have created blank project, now there is just Object.java in objects package and ObjectTest in test directory.

Comment: If you reedited the class you have to post the new code.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: are you sure you're posting your exact code? it occurred to me you may be missing the keyword public if you selected groovy at one point.

Comment: In Files/ ProjectStructure... / Modules / verify that your test directory is known to Intellij as a test directory

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked if you have the JUnit plugin enabled? I (foolishly, shame!) disabled it at some point and was unable to get IDEA to run my tests until I remembered to turn the plugin back on...

Comment: I've no clue why but for some reason JUnit plugin was disabled by default in my IntelliJ Community 2020 upgrade. Went to `File > Settings > Plugins`, checked the box next to JUnit and got my test Run buttons working.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the root directory of your classes. It must be marked as source (for java classes) or test (for java test classes).

It seems that your directory is not well marked in IntelliJ.

Comment: Directory src is marked as source (by default) and now I have exported test class to "test" directory marked as test. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple test and put it on [github](https://github.com/wederbrand/stacktest).

It's the absolute simplest of tests but it works great, standing inside the test class pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will run the test.

Go ahead and clone it and try it out.

Comment: As I thought, it doesn't work. Neither my private code doesn't work. I'm starting to think that is't IDE problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is:

- Open Class in Intellij and press Ctrl+Shift+T
- Select "Create New Test"
- Now, a new pop up will be opened where you can select Unit Test Library (For your case its Junit4)
- Select the methods which you want to include in test
- And there you go !

Comment: This auto-generating thing doesn't solve the problem. I have always created tests by myself.

Comment: @wizzle: Try removing your test class from that directory and regenerate it by above method. This time specify your "test" directory and see the Name of Test class which is already written.

Comment: Then try using TestNG if you have flexibility (TestNG uses JUnit internally)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find that this happens when I try and launch "All tests" from the project folder in the structure view. Launching all tests by right clicking on the test root folder and selecting "all tests" from there seems to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to me.  When I built via Maven it had a problem.  When I fixed the problem, it would run the junits again.  Goofy.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by clicking File-> Invalidate chaces and Invalidate an Restart